# Реализация многопоточности в Python для различных задач

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing

У меня непростой для относительного новичка вопрос, на который мне не удалось найти точного ответа.
Суть вопроса такова, что у меня есть некая программа, которая должна, к примеру, выводить строки. Пока программа запущена, отслеживается нажатие клавиши. При нажатии выводится `ГОТОВСЬ!`, подпрограмма должна подождать n-ое количество времени и после вывести `ПЛИ!`, и во время этой паузы основной поток должен продолжать выводить строки.

Я попробовал реализовать это через `Threading`, `Async` и `Multiprocessing`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что я чего-то не понимаю, что пытаются донести авторы статей про "как бы нам с помощью нескольких поток/процессов загрузить пять картинок из интернета", где создается пул *одинаковых* задач, а не *различных*.

### Примеры программы

Код программы "ГОТОВСЬ! - ПЛИ!"

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard

timing = 0.1

def Shot():
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        print('ГОТОВСЬ!!!######################################')
        sleep(timing)
        print('ПЛИ!!!##########################################')
        return 1
```

**Multiprocessing**

Код основной программы:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from shot import Shot

def showMes():
    while True:
        print('...')



if __name__=='__main__':
    procShowMes = Process(target=showMes)
    procShot = Process(target=Shot)


    procShowMes.start()
    procShot.start()
```

**Threading**

Первый вариант (без join'ов и loop'ом в print'е)

```
from threading import Thread
from shot import Shot

def showMes():
    while True: 
        print('...')

if __name__=='__main__':
    th1 = Thread(target=showMes)
    th2 = Thread(target=Shot)

    th1.start()
    th2.start()
```

Второй вариант (с join'и в loop'е main'а)

```
from threading import Thread
from shot import Shot

def showMes():
    print('...')

if __name__=='__main__':
    th1 = Thread(target=showMes)
    th2 = Thread(target=Shot)
    
    while True:
        th1.start()
        th2.start()

        th1.join()
        th2.join()
```

В это варианте Python жалуется, что не может запустить второй поток, пока не закрыт старый. Хотя понять этого не могу, ведь запускаю `join()`

Так же пробовал пихать `while` в Shot, но это было больше от непонимания, что делать

Надеюсь, суть вопроса я донес. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Непонятно в чём проблема, просто в потоках используйте print и time.sleep в нужном вам порядке

Comment: Проблема в том, что основной поток зависает при использовании time.sleep(), вызванном из вторичного, когда он должен продолжать печатать строки

Comment: У меня ничего не зависает, покажите ваш код

Comment: Изменил вопрос, добавил код

Comment: используй треды

Comment: @eri Написал же, что использовал. Программа встает, когда из второй поток засыпает

Comment: join не забыли?

Comment: и в showMes добавь sleep(0)

Comment: @eri Напишу несколько вариантов с Threading в текст вопроса

Comment: @eri Попробовал добавить sleep() в showMes(), но это не возымело никакого эффекта. Мой цикл продолжает писать строки, но на нажатие клавиш не реагирует

Comment: тут давольно много точек, возможно ваш терминал не успевает их выводить на экран.

Comment: @eri Не совсем понимаю, как точки (как я понял, в принципе выводимые символы) могу повлиять, но я попробовал уменьшить кол-во символов в строках и поиграться с таймингами, однако проблемы с отсутствием отклика это не решило. Я даже через "Ctrl+C" не могу остановить прогу, только принудительно закрывая консоль

Comment: Вообще идея работать с интерфейсом из нескольких тредов - порочная по определению. С интерфейсом должен работать основной тред, дополнительные потоки могут что-то считать, но не работать с интерфейсом. У вас в лучшем случае в интерфейсе будет куча-мала, а в худшем это просто не будет нормально работать.

Comment: @CrazyElf В общем, не получится как-то адекватно реализовать здесь адекватную реализацию параллельного выполнения нескольких функций одновременно? Даже через Event'ы какие-нибудь, и так, чтобы основной поток не останавливался, да?

Comment: Кто-нибудь придумайте вопросу более информативный заголовок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, оно даже и работает, хотя я вам и написал комментарий, что лучше не работать с интерфейсом из разных тредов. Единственное что - я не использовал `keyboard`, поскольку работаю в `Google Colab`, там физическая клавиатура недоступна.

Просто вам надо понять, как работают ваши потоки. Поскольку один поток крутится бесконечно, а другой всё время заканчивается, то и нужно их запускать соответственно - вечный поток запускать один раз, а поток, который всё время прекращается, запускать всё время заново. Примерно так:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    th1 = Thread(target=showMes)
    th1.start()    
    while True:
        th2 = Thread(target=Shot)
        th2.start()
        th2.join()
    th1.join()
```

Ну и, конечно, надо добавить в вечно печатающий поток хоть какую-то паузу, иначе он вообще всё забьёт собой:

```
def showMes():
    while True:
        print('...')
        sleep(timing)
```

До `th1.join()` очередь, конечно, не дойдёт, но лучше сразу учиться писать всё правильно.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Я понял, в каком направлении нужно смотреть, и постараюсь реализовать этот функционал в своей программе

Comment: Единственное, у меня вопрос насчет выхода из программы. Когда я делаю KeyboardInterrupt через Ctrl+C, то основной поток продолжает печатать точки. Что-нибудь можно прописать в программе, чтобы этот поток закрывался при этом условии? Не через Exception ли это делается?

Comment: @9ghtX Если хотите работать с интерфейсом многопоточно, лучше сразу какой-нибудь `tkinter` изучайте, это будет гораздо правильнее, чем вручную ловить клавиши и разруливать потоки.

Comment: там проблема в том, что основная программа будет реализована через OpenCV, где есть отлов нажатия клавиш. Мне нужно было просто понять, как работать с потоками, и сделать так, чтобы выводимая картинка с камеры не зависала, когда происходит опрос внешних устройств

Comment: @9ghtX Ну попробуйте ловить исключение `SysExit` или как его там. Надо продумать, как грамотнее из цикла выйти. Может ваша функция должна что-то возвращать в этом случае, а цикл должен проверять значение

Comment: @9ghtX А, понятно. Ну, в общем, повторюсь, при работе спотоками главное - это осознать, как и что у вас происходит, научиться крутить эти потоки параллельно в голове ну или хотя бы на бумаге. Потом всё просто будет.